# Context: How can I have table of contents with only following sections

Tags: context, context-mkii

I want to have a document with some chapters of frontmatter followed by a table of contents showing all subsequent chapters and endmatter but not the frontmatter

Best I have found is `\completecontent[criterium=all]` but that includes frontmatter

How would I best do this in Context and where is the best place to find such things out in the future?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to replace the `section` with `subject` and the `chapter` with `title`. But that way you loose the numbering. I think that is desired in your case. If it's not, you have to define you own section heads with `\definehead`.

You can use tell the command `\placelist` to print only particular structure types. If you already use `subject` which should be included in the TOC you can easily create your own types based on the existing ones. That way you can retain the numbering.

Example:

```
\definehead
  [NoListSubject]
  [subject]

\definehead
  [NoListSection]
  [section]

\starttext

\placelist [chapter, section]

\NoListSubject {Alpha}
\NoListSection {Beta}
\section {Gamma}
\subject {Delta}

\stoptext
```

The `\definehead` defines a custom structure type based on the second argument. The `subject` is unnumbered, the `section` is numbered.

`\placelist [chapter, section]` places only chapters and sections. The following prints all types:

```
\placelist
  [chapter,
   section,
   NoListSubject,
   NoListSection]
```

Just change the sectioning commands in the frontmatter to custom types and tell `\placelist` which you want to be printed.